# How to map 2 table to 1 entity class with hibernate annotation?

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hibernate. Now I have a problem. I have 2 tables (Timetable, and Timetable_backup) with similar structure because the timetable_backup table is just back up version of timetable table which contains current data. Now I do not know how to get all data from the past to now. In hibernate, we cannot use UNION like in SQL to query. So I try to map 2 tables to 1 entity using Inheritance and @mappedsuperclass but it does not work for me. Please help me with this. If the context is not clear please tell me.

Kind Regards

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is something like [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers), a plugin for Hibernate that takes care of versioning records in a table. You just use a couple of annotations in your classes and it provides an interface to look for past records among other things.

Comment: thankx but it does not work in this case.Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it.

The typical workaround is to map entity to the main table, and use [native SQL queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html) to access the backup table.

Comment: Could you please make a demonstration of your point of view? I am new so I now confuse of what you are saying. silly me. :)

Answer (score 0):

By this time you might have found answer or workaround to the problem you have posted.  If possible, can you please post it here so that it will help others.

Anyway I found following link which explains how to create tables using single POJO [Mapping same POJO to more than one table in Hibernate](http://www.coderanch.com/t/492558/ORM/databases/Mapping-POJO-table-Hibernate-XML).

As hibernate does not support union.  I have extracted results from 2 queried (main table as well as backup table) and used **listTimeTable.addAll(listbackTimeTable);** This will give result same as union all operation.

Once again, please post your implementation for benefit of this community...

Thanks,

Shirish